# Why are there two rectifiers in series in a Terco generation and measurement of direct voltage section?

Tags: voltage, dc

Why are there two rectifiers in series in a Terco generation and measurement of direct voltage section?

[image: Terco Practical Setup]

Comment: What is a "Terco?"

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. You'll notice nearly nobody (probably: only you!) here knows the devices you're referring to. You will need to help us help you by telling us what this does in total, at what voltages, currents this is happening, and which special safety/regulatory constraints apply to it.

Comment: @JRE I think "Terco" is the manufacturer. A [HV9111 Silicon Rectifier](https://www.tercosweden.com/product/hv9111-silicon-rectifier/) is rated for "Inverse Peak voltage: 140 kV" so rather specialised.

Comment: Hasalanka Nagahawaththa - Hi, I linked the site rules to you before. Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the *original* source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the original image source name & link (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks.

Comment: Terco means a High voltage practical equipment design company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why are there two rectifiers in series in a Terco generation and
> measurement of direct voltage section?*

Basically to increase the reverse breakdown withstand voltage from 140 kV to nearly double that value. Big volts! Take great care. This is the sort of experiment they are used for: -

[image]

Image taken from the brochure linked on [this site](https://www.tercosweden.com/products/)

Comment: There, all the diodes are forward-biased. Is not it?

Comment: It depends on the polarity of the applied voltage @HasalankaNagahawaththa